# C++ Generic component system

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am trying to implement Entity-Components like in Unity3D in C++. What I would like to do is something that can be easily achieved in C#:

```
public T GetComponent<T>() where T : Component
    {
        foreach (Component component in _components)
        {
            if (component is T)
                return component as T;
        }
        
        return null;
    }
```

However when I try to write the c++ equivalent which looks like this:

```
template <class T>
Component& getComponent()
{
    for (auto component : componentList)
    {
        if (dynamic_cast<T>(*component) != nullptr) 
        {
            return *component;
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following compiler error: 'T': invalid target type for dynamic_cast.
Is there a different way to approach this problem?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: You havn't shown the type of `componentList`, so the type if `component` is not clear. Also, what is `T` in this example? You should cast from one pointer to another, or from one reference to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) requires that the expression being casted, and the type being casted to, are *pointers* (or references).

You can't use `dynamic_cast` without using either pointers or references.

So the solution is *probably*:

```
if (dynamic_cast<T*>(component) != nullptr)
```